# Azure Notification Hub iOS template not accepting badge field anymore?

Tags: xamarin, azure-notificationhub

We are registering for template push notifications using Xamarin's Azure Messaging component.
So far we've used the following template to register to notifications:

```
@"{""aps"": {""alert"": ""$(message)"",""badge"": ""$(badge)"",""sound"": ""$(sound)""}}"
```

We are passing this string to the `Hub.RegisterTemplateAsync` in the iOS app.

Since some time ago (less than a month), the call to `RegisterTemplateAsync` generates the following response:

```
Apr  3 13:35:03 iPhone MyApp[352] <Warning>: Error Response:<Error><Code>400</Code><Detail>The supplied notification payload is invalid.TrackingId:5dbf4199-cf52-4245-b8e4-acfa4e00cfee_G7,TimeStamp:4/3/2016 10:35:04 AM</Detail></Error>
Apr  3 13:35:03 iPhone MyApp[352] <Warning>: -------------> Notifications: RegisterTemplateAsync error: Fail to perform registration operation. Response:<Error><Code>400</Code><Detail>The supplied notification payload is invalid.TrackingId:5dbf4199-cf52-4245-b8e4-acfa4e00cfee_G7,TimeStamp:4/3/2016 10:35:04 AM</Detail></Error>
```

It is exactly the same binary which used to work. Now it doesn't.

When troubleshooting the issue, we found out the problem is the `badge` field. When we remove it, the registration to the notification hub succeeds:

```
@"{""aps"": {""alert"": ""$(message)"",""sound"": ""$(sound)""}}";
```

So now we have a broken production app in AppStore that can  no longer get notifications.

Is this something that changed on the hub side or is there a chance that we did something wrong?

Comment: Do you have an example of a notification message that you are sending to the Notification Hub? Are you sure that you are sending the badge value as a number and not a string? Because everything looks correct to me.

Comment: The error I'm getting is during registration of the client. Not when I send a notification but when I call `Hub.RegisterTemplateAsync`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using ""#(badge)"" instead of ""$(badge)""?

Comment: I would also try:    @"{'aps': {'alert': '$(message)','badge': #(badge),'sound': '$(sound)'}}"

Comment: `#(badge)` works. Thanks! Do you know if this is documented somewhere (didn't see anything in the REST api docs or any of the tutorials)?